# How to Convert JSON Object Array String to JSON Object Array to Custom Class in Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am new in C# and Xamarin and want to convert json object array string to json object array to custom class in c#.

```
string test = @"{firstName: ""Sample First Name"", lastName: ""Sample Last Name""}";
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject sample = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(test);
Console.WriteLine(sample);
```

The return will be like this which is correct:

```
{
     "firstName": "Sample First Name",
     "lastName": "Sample Last Name"
}
```

I think this is working since it is a single object but it is not working if my json object array string is like this which is I am getting from the response.

```
string test2 = @"[{firstName: ""Sample First Name"", lastName: ""Sample Last Name""},{firstName: ""Sample First Name 2"", lastName: ""Sample Last Name 2""}]";
```

How will i convert test2 to json object array?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Incorrect json you have

Comment: hi @viveknuna, What is the error in the json?

Comment: [{
 "firstName": "Sample First Name",
 "lastName": "Sample Last Name"
}, {
 "firstName": "Sample First Name 2",
 "lastName": "Sample Last Name 2"
}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you didn't parse it into a custom class. You could do however:

```
public class Data
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// ...
var test2 = @"[{firstName: ""Sample First Name"", lastName: ""Sample Last Name""},{firstName: ""Sample First Name 2"", lastName: ""Sample Last Name 2""}]";
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(test2);
```

Comment: @ron glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

to test it you can use the snippet below.

```
var s =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
var myObject = eval('(' + s + ')');
for (i in myObject)
{
   alert(myObject[i]["name"]);
}
```

hop it will help you

OR 
creat class of json object

then insert json data in to that object

use jsonConverter Deserializer to DeserializeObject

```
var objects_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid Json should be.

```
[{
    "firstName": "Sample First Name",
    "lastName": "Sample Last Name"
}, {
    "firstName": "Sample First Name 2",
    "lastName": "Sample Last Name 2"
}]

public class Data
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Code to deserilize json.

```
Data result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(test);
```